# My Connect Four game is returning complete at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My connect four game is not validating anything and is just showing true right at the beginning when the program starts.

I have tried to use a big array list and keep track of where everything goes in.

```
private boolean areFourConnected(){ 
    for (int j = 0; j<rows-3 ; j++ ){
        for (int i = 0; i<columns; i++){
            if (this.cells[i][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i][j+1].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i][j+2].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i][j+3].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer()){
                return true;
            }           
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<columns-3 ; i++ ){
        for (int j = 0; j<this.rows; j++){
            if (this.cells[i][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i+1][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i+2][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i+3][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer()){
                return true;
            }           
        }
    }
    for (int i=3; i<columns; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<rows-3; j++){
            if (this.cells[i][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i-1][j+1].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i-2][j+2].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i-3][j+3].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer())
                return true;
        }
    }
    for (int i=3; i<columns; i++){
        for (int j=3; j<rows; j++){
            if (this.cells[i][j].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i-1][j-1].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i-2][j-2].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer() && this.cells[i-3][j-3].getPlayer() == cells[i][j].getPlayer())
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually debug it. Manual debugging is a great way to learn how to program.

Manual debugging works like this: Forget the computer for a second. Just look at the code, and become the computer: Use paper if you have to, but, write down exactly what you think the code is actually going to do. For every statement executed, what are the values you'd expect each variable to hold? Does it enter the if, or skip it? etcetera.

Then, run the actual code and observe what the actual execution does. Use a debugger. If you don't have access to one, make do with System.out.println statements.

The exact location where the code does something different from what you think it should do, is usually when the problem with your code becomes clear.

Do so here and you'll figure it out soon.

I'll give you a hint: Presumably, .getPlayer() returns 0 for a blank cell, 1 for a cell where player 1 has put their chip in, and a 2 if player 2 has. 0.. is equal to 0.